# Unix: chaining commands

Tags: unix, cd, chain

I have learned that ';' is equivalent to 'enter' in the command line. But I have this situation.

My directory has the following configuration: Directory A contains directories B and C. In currently in directory B. I do the following:

> > cd ../

that takes me to A, of course. Then I do:

> > cd C

that takes me to C.

However, if I chain the two commands, starting in B again:

> > (cd ../ ; cd C)

I still stay in B. What is going on? Why does it not take me to C?

Comment: What shell are you using? Also, why not just use `cd ../C` ?

Comment: use `cd ../ && cd C` - I suspect the `;` starts a new process.  The `a && b` means if the `a` command succeeds, do `b`, using the same process.

Comment: @kfmfe04 That is false. `(   )` starts a subshell process; `;` is just like `&&` but unconditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process that you start when you execute `( cd ../; cd C)` has its own environment, and therefore its own current working directory.  This is demonstrable below:

```
dogface@computer ~/A/B
$ ( cd .. ; pwd ; cd C; pwd )
/home/dogface/A
/home/dogface/A/C

dogface@computer ~/A/B
$ pwd
/home/dogface/A/B
```

Now try without the '(' and ')' ...

```
dogface@computer ~/A/B
$ cd .. ; cd C

dogface@computer ~/A/C
$ pwd
/home/dogface/A/C
```

Comment: so when it finishes, it always return to its original directory?

Comment: @quannguyen No; your original shell's working directory was never changed.

Comment: Its the '(' and ')', when you use `( shell commands )` you are tell the shell to start a child process and execute the "shell commands" in that child's environment.  Maybe you can see what I mean if you execute: `( cd .. ; sleep 10 ; pwd ; cd C )` and in another shell execute `ps -ef --forest`. You should see all the processes laid out.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this instead:

```
cd .. && cd C
```

Alternatively, your original command should work if you remove the parentheses:

```
cd ../ ; cd C
```

Parentheses cause the command(s) to be executed in a subshell, which is why you're not seeing the directory change.  See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parenthesis-interpreted-at-the-command-line) for more details.

Comment: `&&` is safer as the first `cd` command has to succeed before the second is executed.